# Is there a way to make a link open in a new tab or window in SE?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hyperlinks

Gads, just typing this question I see a lot of negative scores for it.

But it really is a valid question.

It is easy in HTML to add the target="_blank" to the link.

My reason for asking is that when I use links in my answers, especially when explaining FCC rules in [Ham Radio SE](https://ham.stackexchange.com/) I always make sure that the concept is self-explanatory without clicking on the link, but if someone does, then they might spend some time in that referenced official document and forget to come back and read the rest of my answers, which are sometimes a clever spin on the rules document.

I am not going to try to hack SE, so instead I am just asking the question.

Is there a way I don't know about, or can this feature be added?

Comment: Oh, please no. I want to kill those links with a dagger. If I want the link to open in a new tab, I'll do that myself. Even if I do change my mind after opening it in the same tab, there's still the back button.

Comment: OK.  I accept that as a valid point.  If that function existed I suppose it should be an option and not a surprise.  And really, that's what we have right now.  We can do it ourselves if that is our choice.

Comment: As a general rule, when I find a link in a post I'll do the "open in new tab" option so that I _don't_ forget about the post. Also, so that when I'm done reading the link I can close that tab and be back where I started - since many times one link leads to an ever-expanding reading list. The part that always trips me up is the image links. I invariably forget to open them in a new tab, and once viewed my habit to close the tab leaves me trying to find the post again. Totally my fault, yet totally frustrating too. :(

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't.

[SE mostly uses its own dialect of markdown with a few small changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You cannot use bare html tags most of the time (except a few tags like kbd). As things are now, its not a feature.

In this case, you're just going to have to ensure your answer is more entertaining than the link and that the reader does not get stuck down a rabbit hole.

As a feature request, who knows, but considering SE answers are supposed to be self-contained for most part it really feels like the utility of this would be somewhat limited.

Comment: OK, I see your point.  And I do't want to get into the tag business anyway.  My HTML-production days are pretty much over now.

Comment: For the most part, questions _are_ self-contained. At least, after a few edits anyway. Still, examining the source - for more information, or to verify the _claim_ in the answer - is common (in my practice at least). As an autodidact I frequently _jump_ down into the _rabbit hole_ just to see where it leads. 3 hours later I find the trail of "back button" clicks can seem endless, and having the _rabbit hole_ on a different tab leaves me a life-line in the form of the original tab. Unfortunately, for most people the new tab action on links is annoying, so I don't see that happening on SE :(

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a declined feature request - and I suppose considering the comments, I could have worded it a bit better. Don't forget, SE isn't going to know what its users would want or not want without meta posts like this, good or bad. Whether its practical is a whole nother kettle of fish.